# Set of weights of dual representation $V^*$ in terms of weights of $V$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras, representation-of-algebras

Let $\frak{g}$ be a finite dimensional semisimple Lie algebra and let $V$ be a $\frak{g}$-module. I've been trying to show that the set of weights $\Psi(V^*)$ of the dual module coincides with $-\Psi(V)$, the negative weights of our initial module $V$. It's eassy to do it whenever $V$ is finite dimensional and it's also relatively eassy to do it more generally, whenever $V$ is in the BGG category $\mathcal{O}$, in fact I think you only need $V$ to be $\frak{h}$-semisimple, where $\frak{h}$ is a Cartan of $\frak{g}$.
My question is whether this is true for an arbitrary infinite dimensional module that might or might not be $\frak{h}$-semisimple.
Proofs or counterexamples are welcome.

Comment: Note that in the BGG category O, the dual is defined differently: it usually is twisted by the Chevalley involution (this affects exactly what the weights of the dual are, but not the spirit of the question), but more crucially the dual of a representation $V$ is not the vector space dual $V^*$: instead one first breaks $V$ apart into $\bigoplus V_\lambda$, duals each finite-dimensional piece individually, then reassembles them into $\bigoplus V_\lambda^*$. This is why the proposition works in $\mathcal{O}$.

Comment: I know about what you said but this does not answer my question. I am specifically asking about the weights of the the dual vector space regarded as a $\frak{g}$-module under the usual action, not the twisted one.

Comment: The twisted action was a bit of a red herring sorry, my point was that the underlying vector space of the dual in category $\mathcal{O}$ is not the same as the underlying vector space of the dual in the category of representations of Lie algebras more generally (at least whenever the representation $V$ is infinite-dimensional). Do you know if your question is true for the algebraic dual of a Verma module, for instance?

Comment: If we forget about the $\mathcal{O}$ for a second and just use that the Verma $M(\lambda)$ is $\frak{h}$-semisimple, then afer fixing a basis which we can always take it to consist of weight vectors then the isomorphism $M(\lambda)\longrightarrow M(\lambda)^*$ resitricts to an isomorphism $M(\lambda)_\mu\longrightarrow (M(\lambda)^*)_{-\mu}$ and thus yes, the weights of the usual vector space dual of the Verma module are precisely the negatives of the weights of the Verma module. I'm asking whether this is true if the module in question is not $\frak{h}$-semisimple.

Comment: I guess my point is that there is no isomorphism $M(\lambda) \to M(\lambda)^*$ if you consider $M(\lambda)^*$ to be the algebraic dual (i.e. we are working in the general category of Lie algebra representations, rather than $\mathcal{O}$). Because of the general fact that if $V$ is countably infinite-dimensional, then $V^*$ is uncountably-infinite dimensional. At any rate one needs to be careful. I still can't think of any counterexample in the case of Verma modules though.

Comment: Ah yes I see what you're talking about now. So this might only be true in the case where $V$ is finite dimensional?

Comment: I suspect that what you're saying is true. Some notation: if $V$ is $\mathfrak{h}$-semisimple, with finite-dimensional weight spaces, then write $V^\vee$ for the restricted dual (the direct sum of duals of weight spaces). In this case we have $(V^\vee)^\vee \cong V$ as vector spaces (and as $\mathfrak{g}$-representations, I think). And clearly the set of weights of $V^\vee$ are precisely the negatives of $V$ (and even their multiplicities match up). Since $V^\vee \subseteq V^*$, this shows that $V^*$ has at least the weight spaces we want (it might have more)...

Comment: ...but I suspect that the $\mathfrak{h}$-semisimplicity will force $V^*$ to have only those "obvious" weight spaces. Note that if $V$ is infinite dimensional then there is a huge gap between $V^\vee$ and $V^*$, and $V^*$ need not be a weight representation, so perhaps it is not so exciting that it has the weight spaces we want, since this captures almost none of the whole representation.